# Typescript functions with same name in multiple files

Tags: typescript

I'm moving an existing JavaScript app into TypeScript, but struggling with how to achieve this:

In JavaScript I could optionally declare a function on each page then call that function from a global file if it exists

In global.js:

```
function globalFunc() {
    if (window.pageFunc) {
        pageFunc();
    }
}
```

And on each page (optionally):

```
function pageFunc() {
    ...
}
```

The biggest problem in Typescript is the obvious 'Duplicate function implementation' error.

There are a few reasons for doing this; but a good real example is registering window events to control the order of actions; e.g. (in global.js):

```
window.onresize = function() {
    //global resize actions
    ...
    if (window.pageResizeFunc) {
        pageResizeFunc();
    }
}
```

Any tips on how I should implement this in TypeScript?

Comment: Can I ask what you are using this for? There are several ways of solving this issue and the best choice depends on how the rest of the project is being implemented

Comment: Declare a `Page` interface with an optional `pageFunc` method. Have each page declare a class that implements that interface. Store that page value in `window.page` as a `Page`. Then in your `globalFunc`, look for `pageFunc in window.page` and run it if it's there.

Comment: I think I would compile each page separately. ie: compile global.ts and page1.ts into page1.js and global.ts and page2.ts into page2.js etc.

Comment: @RyanSchaefer I've added an example - thanks!

Comment: @HereticMonkey thanks; I played with this, but could quite get it to come together; it led me the dirty solution I came up with (posted); but maybe you have a better answer?

Comment: @DaveCousineau seems like a good idea, but I'm concerned it would cause too many other issues in my setup

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a solution, although it feels quite dirty!

In global.**ts**:

```
function globalFunc() {
    if ((<any>window)) {
        (<any>window).pageFunc();
    }
}
```

And on each page (optionally):

```
(<any>window).pageFunc = function() {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could add your definition for `pageFunc` to the Window interface as a [global augmentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html#global-augmentation). Using `any` castings everywhere pretty much defeats the point for using Typescript. See below.

```
declare global {
    interface Window {
        pageFunc?(...args: unknown[]): void;
    }
}

function globalFunc() {
    if (window.pageFunc) {
        window.pageFunc();
    }
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?&install-plugin=typescript-playground-link-shortener#code/CYUwxgNghgTiAEBzCB7ARlC8DeAoeB8AlgHYAuIMAZlGAgOqnAoDuO+hnADlIiAGIBXEmAD8ACgB002IgDOALnjCA1iVYkA2gF0AlEoBuKIsADcHAgF9c13FWFgyRFCSSoMEISPG72nIlTw4ixMrJI8fF5gvnicnCEkzCzhvAIOPuac1rYA9DnwALZQKghkcvBwYCiIJEQAXqUAFkTlVEQQCFDlUIUowIIduCAAHlwoMGQ4luZAA)

Comment: Thanks for this; what does the declaration of pageFunc on each page look like?  This what's tripping me up

Comment: @BenRobinson you can simply add your `pageFunc` declaration to the window object on each of your page files. However to have each of your page files recognize that `pageFunc` exists on `window`, you might want to use [ambient modules](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html#ambient-modules).